# Send a message with SignalR

Tags: sockets, client, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to send a message to a person with SignalR. How can I get the ConnectionID data of the connecting person?

Can only send a message with the ConnectionID data?
***What kind of method do I need to follow?***

**Clients.User(ConnectionId).send(message);** Is the syntax correct?

Thank you ...

Comment: Out of the following modes of message sending, what is the exact did you meant?
1 - Reply to a message.
2 - Send a message to selected user out of a set of connected users. In this scenario, I expect you do have a userid for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ConnectionId from the Context from your hub class. (`Context.ConnectionId`). When you have the connectionID you can send message to the specific client by

```
 hub.Clients.Client(connectionId).MethodName(message);
```